# Formatting decimals without rounding

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and was wondering if someone could help out with the below code. I am having trouble finding an IF statement to insert into "---------INSERT IF STATEMENT HERE". I am utilizing SQL Convert(Decimal (28,10)) to limit numerical values to 10 decimal spots. Basically, I would like to remove zero's within the report designer by utilizing C#. Few examples below:

Preferred formatting: 4.25 vs 4.2500000000
Preferred formatting: 0.00 vs 0.0000000000

No point having extra zeroes.
Current Notional Amount : 22,000,000.00

Hypothetical example:

22,000,000.12344567890 (up to 10 decimals when available)

I was able to remove zero's with the below code; however, I am limited to two zero's for all my numerical values. So 4.2500000000 shows as 4.25, but 4.2511 would actually show up as 4.25. Can someone please help?

```
public void Detail1_Format()
{ DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox tb1;
String s;
Double d;
String ColName;
s = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text;
ColName = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtColName1"]).Text;
if((ColName == "Price") || (ColName == "Shares (Par or Notional)"))
{
    if(Double.TryParse(s, out d) == true)
    {
        d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        tb1 = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"];
---------INSERT IF STATEMENT HERE
        {tb1.Text = d.ToString("#,###.##########");}
---------else {
        {tb1.Text = d.ToString("#,###.00");
        }
        ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text = tb1.Text;}
}
else {
    ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text;
}
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you can try `.TrimEnd('0');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I was able to modify your suggestion, Kirk and add additional logic. I added another variable (d2) and inserted one more if statement to allow for more than 2 decimal places for values such as 103.123456. Please see below:

```
public void Detail1_Format()
{ DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox tb1;
String s;
Double d;
Decimal d2;
String ColName;
s = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text;
ColName = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtColName1"]).Text;
if((ColName == "Price" || ColName == "Original Face Value" || ColName == "Shares"))
{
    if(Double.TryParse(s, out d) == true)
    {
        d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        tb1 = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"];
        d2 = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
        if((BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d2)[3])[2]) > 2)
        {tb1.Text = d.ToString("#,##0.00########");}
        else 
        {tb1.Text = d.ToString("#,###.00");
        }
        ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text = tb1.Text;}
}
else {
    ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text = ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"]).Text;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand, you want to remove trailing 0s beyond 2 decimal places and possibly have 10 decimals.

If so, you are very close and you can tweak some things with the simple string formatting to do this.

```
d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
tb1 = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.TextBox) rpt.Sections["Detail1"].Controls["txtValue1"];
tb1.Text = d.ToString("#,##0.00########");
```

Here the format `#,##0.00########` will require 2 decimal places (signified by a `0`) and the remaining 8 are optional (signified by a `#`).

**Examples**

```
Convert.ToDecimal("0.0000000000").ToString("#,##0.00########"); // 0.00
Convert.ToDecimal("4.2500000000").ToString("#,##0.00########"); // 4.25
Convert.ToDecimal("22,000,000.1234567890").ToString("#,##0.00########"); // 22,000,000.123456789
Convert.ToDecimal("22,000,000.1234567891").ToString("#,##0.00########"); // 22,000,000.1234567891
```

Comment: To clarify - I would like to have up to 10 decimal places with numerical values that don't have trailing zero's. For example, I am interested in displaying 103.1234567891 or 103.23453 (without rounding), but not 103.23456890 or 103.23400. Furthermore, I only want to display two decimal places if there are only zero's after the decimal. For example, I want to show 103.00 instead of 103.000000000, which I successfully accomplished in the code I posted; however, the numerical values are being limited to only two decimal places now.